# PHP code in localhost not working in server - with phantomjs

Tags: php, phantomjs, file-permissions, webpage-screenshot

I am using a php script from [github](https://github.com/microweber/screen) to capture *screenshot* of a website. Its working fine in *localhost*. But not working after uploading the same code to my server (*linux* hosting). I tried uploading to multiple servers. None of them worked. No error codes are coming.

In the documentation, it says:

> Make the bin executable chmod +x /var/www/html/screen/bin/phantomjs,
>
> Make your folder writable

I am not sure what does that mean, so i set file permissions of whole files and folder to `777`. Still not working

**How did i upload to my server.**

I uploaded the whole code to the server. Changed file permissions of all directories and files to 777 using FileZilla. I have attached a screenshot of
it.
[image]

Comment: No errrors at all? Does the script work when you run it manually? Have you checked that phantomjs really is at /var/www/html/screen/bin/phantomjs on the real server ?

Comment: Yes. I tried it manually. The link is http://wdudes.com/demo/screen-master/shot.php?url=google.com

But how to locate it? Whats the need of it? I didn't get

Comment: Please update question with telling about how you deployed the script on the server, with complete paths and permission you've set. Otherwise it's going to be a long string of comments here.

Comment: @Vaviloff ok. I have updated the question with all details. Pls check it

Comment: Have you set the permissions recursively?

Comment: yes. I selected recursively and "apply to all files and directories"

Comment: some server doesn't have PHP-GD library installed. if you're working with image processing check for GD lib. using php info method. and install it.

Comment: but i have used the same code in the same server 2 years back. It was working

Comment: Yes. I contacted server guys, they said it is supported by default

Comment: What hosting do you use, is it by a chance a shared(virtual) hosting? Do you have SSH access? Can you log in to server via SSH, go to the `bin` directory where phantomjs is and run `./phantomjs --version` ?

Comment: i am on shared hosting. I don't have ssh access

Comment: Then most probably you can't execute external programs with PHP, hence can't launch PhantomJS. I would strongly recommend to buy a cheap VPS (find one at lowendbox.com or just buy one from digitalocean/vultr) and experiment on it, while learning Linux server basics.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is still permissions issue, You need to set the proper permissions using putty.

```
 1. Login using putty
 2. Open root directory
 3. Set permissions file and folder using this command
     ===> chmod -R 777 folder name
```

Comment: To change permissions for all folders and files is a really bad idea.

Comment: I already tried setting permission using Filezilla. No change. Is it same when we use puty?